# avahi-daemon.service failed

Tags: avahi

Tried to browse services with `avahi-browse -alr`:

```
Failed to create client object: Daemon not running
```

And actually there is a problem with the avahi daemon:

```
● avahi-daemon.service - Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/avahi-daemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2015-09-16 08:50:23 CEST; 4s ago
  Process: 6888 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/avahi-daemon -s (code=exited, status=255)
 Main PID: 6888 (code=exited, status=255)
   Status: "avahi-daemon 0.6.31 starting up."

Found user 'avahi' (UID 107) and group 'avahi' (GID 118).
Successfully dropped root privileges.
avahi-daemon 0.6.31 starting up.
Successfully called chroot().
Successfully dropped remaining capabilities.
Loading service file /services/udisks.service.
Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
avahi-daemon.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Unit avahi-daemon.service entered failed state.
avahi-daemon.service failed.
```

Ubuntu 15.04. So, logs show nothing. What can be done?

**update**

Today logs show `Failed to create server: Invalid domain name`. The search can begin.

Comment: Since I am not allowed to comment: What does starting the service manually (from the command line, as the user avahi) say? as root: su - avahi /usr/sbin/avahi-daemon -s

Comment: That command doesn't work: `su: option requires an argument -- 's'`. I tried `su - avahi '/usr/sbin/avahi-daemon -s'`: nothing happens, no logs, exit status is '1'. Same for `su - avahi /usr/sbin/avahi-daemon`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My `avahi-daemon.conf` is messed up and know why...

Anyways, `domain-name` is set to `alocal`, possibly in the panic to fix some samba share problems.