# apt install fails because of avahi-daemon.service (20.04)

Tags: apt, services, avahi

I am trying to install a program with `apt install` (or `apt-get install`) but it always fails due to an error with the avahi-daemon.

See below (ignore the program wine is already installed. This happens with any program  I try):

```
bgc@jadzia:~$ sudo apt-get install wine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
wine is already the newest version (5.0-3ubuntu1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  glib-networking:i386 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386 
  ...cut out a lot here as i don't think it's relevant...
  ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 remmina-common shim va-driver-all:i386 vdpau-driver-all:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up avahi-daemon (0.7-4ubuntu7.1) ...
Job for avahi-daemon.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status avahi-daemon.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript avahi-daemon, action "restart" failed.
● avahi-daemon.service - Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/avahi-daemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2022-09-28 22:17:19 PDT; 7ms ago
TriggeredBy: ● avahi-daemon.socket
    Process: 388962 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/avahi-daemon -s (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)
   Main PID: 388962 (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)

Sep 28 22:17:19 jadzia systemd[1]: Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
Sep 28 22:17:19 jadzia avahi-daemon[388962]: Assignment outside group in /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf:21 <AVAHI_DAEMON_DETECT_LOCAL=0>
Sep 28 22:17:19 jadzia systemd[1]: avahi-daemon.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION
Sep 28 22:17:19 jadzia systemd[1]: avahi-daemon.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 28 22:17:19 jadzia systemd[1]: Failed to start Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
dpkg: error processing package avahi-daemon (--configure):
 installed avahi-daemon package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 avahi-daemon
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've no clue what avahi-daemon is, but googling has indicated I may need to edit the file `/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf`. It seems to be something network related (I guess that's the DNS in Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD).

In particular, I've seen suggestions to change the `domain-name`. Such as [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674683/avahi-daemon-service-failed) and [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/avahi-daemon-error-messages-that-may-be-solved-by-editing-the-configuration-file-4175672196/). That line in my file was commented out. I've tried uncommenting it, changing it to `alocal` and `localhost`, but that has had no effect. Below is my .conf file.

```
# This file is part of avahi.
#
# avahi is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
# under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as
# published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the
# License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
# avahi is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT
# ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY
# or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU General Public
# License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
# License along with avahi; if not, write to the Free Software
# Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA 02111-1307
# USA.

# See avahi-daemon.conf(5) for more information on this configuration
# file!

AVAHI_DAEMON_DETECT_LOCAL=0

[server]
#host-name=foo
#domain-name=local
#browse-domains=0pointer.de, zeroconf.org
use-ipv4=yes
use-ipv6=yes
#allow-interfaces=eth0
#deny-interfaces=eth1
#check-response-ttl=no
#use-iff-running=no
#enable-dbus=yes
#disallow-other-stacks=no
#allow-point-to-point=no
#cache-entries-max=4096
#clients-max=4096
#objects-per-client-max=1024
#entries-per-entry-group-max=32
ratelimit-interval-usec=1000000
ratelimit-burst=1000

[wide-area]
enable-wide-area=yes

[publish]
#disable-publishing=no
#disable-user-service-publishing=no
#add-service-cookie=no
#publish-addresses=yes
publish-hinfo=no
publish-workstation=no
#publish-domain=yes
#publish-dns-servers=192.168.50.1, 192.168.50.2
#publish-resolv-conf-dns-servers=yes
#publish-aaaa-on-ipv4=yes
#publish-a-on-ipv6=no

[reflector]
#enable-reflector=no
#reflect-ipv=no

[rlimits]
#rlimit-as=
#rlimit-core=0
#rlimit-data=8388608
#rlimit-fsize=0
#rlimit-nofile=768
#rlimit-stack=8388608
#rlimit-nproc=3
```

I've also tried starting the service manually, which fails

```
bgc@jadzia:~$ /etc/init.d/dbus start
Starting dbus (via systemctl): dbus.serviceFailed to start dbus.service: Operation refused, unit dbus.service may be requested by dependency only (it is configured to refuse manual start/stop).
See system logs and 'systemctl status dbus.service' for details.
 failed!
```

And tried editing line 21 that appears in the error message: `AVAHI_DAEMON_DETECT_LOCAL=0`. Tried changing it to `=1` and commenting it out. Still fails.

This issue effectively prevents me from updating or installing a lot of new software. I also can't seem to upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04, perhaps this is related?

Any idea what's causing this and how to resolve it?

Comment: PLEASE do not upgrade or try to upgrade a broken system, Fix all issues before an upgrade.

Comment: Uh... This is me asking how to fix the issue...

Comment: Ultimately I was never able to find a solution to this issue and due to some other, probably unrelated issues that I was having trouble addressing, I just wiped and reinstalled the entire OS. Now it works great!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

I commented out the lines:
ratelimit-interval-usec=1000000
ratelimit-burst=1000

and
enable-dbus=no

Not sure if this is advisable, but I can now do an "apt upgrade" with no errors.

Comment: I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: Ultimately I was never able to find a solution to this issue and due to some other, probably unrelated issues that I was having trouble addressing, I just wiped and reinstalled the entire OS. Now it works great!